# When using EntityFramework to List<table> returns invalid rows?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm creating a simple WinForms tool that uses RankTrackr API and then awaits the callback to update the database table upon completion.

Before completion:

**Keyword**: has value, **PostID**: has value, **Returned**: `false`, **URL**: `null`, **TimePosted**: `DateTime.Now`, **TimeBack**: `null`

After completion (this is what the tool waits for):

**Keyword**: has value, **PostID**: has value, **Returned**: `true`, **URL**: has value, **TimePosted**: has value, **TimeBack**: `DateTime.Now`

**Problem:** When querying the database for-

```
List<ranktrackrTesting> KeywordList = db.ranktrackrTestings.Where(x =>
(x.PostID >= fpid && x.PostID <= lpid && x.URL != null)).ToList();
```

It returns with items, which are correct, lets say if 2 rows are needed, it will return them two rows to the list *however* notice `x.URL != null`.

This is how the list looks like:

[image: List from database]

Why is URL `null` when I specifically queried for it not to be null. Plus the only way the tool get's to this point is when all have returned with data in the URL column. I've checked in the database serval times and it runs and data does get inserted in to the correct row as seen below:

[image: Row from database, after completion]

Could someone help with this? Thanks in advance.

It seems like it hasn't updated in the List correctly and it looks how it would have been before completion.

Screenshot of the tool:

[image: Screenshot of tool]

The export button becomes enabled when all rows have returned as completed with `URL != null` then the problem occurs when it is clicked. Then the tool will try to put all the entries in a `List<table>` and give the correct rows however the URL will be `null`.

Comment: Are there 3 rows instead of 2? in the figure one expanded and two others below it? what are other two

Comment: In the list? That's dynamic, it's dependant on what the user needs, this could entail there to be 50 rows needed or just 1. The `fpid` and `lpid` are the first and last PostIDs when I inserted to the table for the first time before I got a response. However they are all the same.

Comment: one thing i carefully see in your figure that first figure shows the details of ID=366 whereas 2nd figure shows one record having ID=350 which is different ID

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that confusion. I just used figure 2 as an example, they are always the matching PostIDs.

Comment: are you sure that the property URL is mapped correctly to the field URL in your database? if you retrieved all the details in the table, you will get some values in the URL property or all will be null?

Comment: Try to check what the generated query is, either by using database profiler tools, or checking what [query EF is generating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework), maybe that will give you some hints

Comment: @HadiHassan it is correct yes, here is a screenshot proving this: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/nTn2GDx.jpg)

Comment: can you provide the sql statement generated by this linq? u can use the profiler to catch the executed sql statement

Comment: @AidonHudson, can you show your entity class, as well as any configuration made it it?

Comment: Can you try this `List<ranktrackrTesting> KeywordList = db.ranktrackrTestings.Where(x =>x.PostID >= fpid && x.PostID <= lpid && x.URL != null && !x.URL.Equals("")).ToList();`